# Sqoop import from MySQL: Decimals always imported into Hive as String

Tags: mysql, string, decimal, cloudera, sqoop

I'm trying to import data from MySQL into Hive (Cloudera 5.8 cluster) with 4 data nodes for HDFS. Using Sqoop 1.4.6 (enclosed in Cloudera 5.8) I've been trying to import directly from MySQL into Hive and it works except..all my Decimal (18,2) fields form MySQL tables (InnoDB format) are always imported as a Hive String data type which is obviously wrong. Here is my Sqoop bash (on CentOS 6.7) script":

```
sqoop import --null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '\0D' --fields-terminated-by '\001' --connect jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx/live_data --username (user_name) --password 'xxxxxx' --table (table name) --hive-import --hive-database (hive_database) --hive-table (table name) --target-dir "(target directory)" --as-parquetfile --hive-overwrite --map-column-hive 'price=DECIMAL\(18%2C2\)'
```

The `map-column-hive` seems to be allowed (meaning, no errors, although I've read of fixes in 1.4.7) and I've substituted "%2C" for a comma (as you get an error when you use a "," directly").

I've checked the Hive Decimal Type and a size of 18,2 appears to be supported (cloudera 5.1+). I've tried a number of variations: using double quotes instead of single quites, removing all delimiter specifiers using

```
("-null-string '\\N' --null-non-string '\\N' --hive-delims-replacement '\0D' --fields-terminated-by '\001'")
```

which really helped for XML data another table, mucked up the data before I used those settings).

I've also tried reducing the number of digits  (for example 8,2) but no matter what I do I seems to get my decimals from MySQL are all converted into the Hive string type which is terrible for numeric aggregate functions.

I've looked into upgrading my Sqoop to 1.4.7 but I've had errors when running it after compiling which is a separate question. For some reason either my `map-column-hive` parameter is ignored or isn't working.

Does anyone have an answer how I can get this to properly import from decimal (18,2) into Hive Decimal (18,2) or at least a shorter number with 2 decimal places.

Thanks all!

Comment: Please use code formats.

Comment: Okay some additional information: I created a table in Impala manually (Note: you MUST import storage file format if you want Sqoop to import into it with the --as-parquetfile format or you get an "Unknown Format" error form the Kite library)  with my desired decimal 18,2 field, but when I tried to use Sqoop to import I get this error:  ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Cannot convert unsupported type: decimal(18,2). It's as if it doesn't support export from MySQL decimal format.

Comment: try the same thing for `textfile` and pre-create hive table with decimal field to identify if it's an issue with `parquetfile`

Comment: The cvs files are problematic unless you specify not only the field separators but the line terminators as well. General online examples don't work 100% but basically when linking a cvs to a table be certain the specify the line terminators in addition to the field terminators or it WILL corrupt the data. My solution in the end was to take the data with the existing mistyped decimal->string conversion by sqoop, create an internal table and insert from the old table into the new one with with a select statment with explicit casting of ALL fields. That seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop Import + Parquet + Decimal is broken. It's fixed for avro here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1493

You can try converting into double using `--map-column-hive`.

Comment: Note: does not work with `--hive-import` and `--as-parquetfile`.